# Ínstalar Intellij Idea en un S.O de 32bits en Windows 32 bits

Tags: intellij-idea, instalacion

Hola gente ¿Como están? Estoy precisando realizar la instalación de Intelli j idea 32bit community en mi pc con Windows 32 bit pero no he podido.
Desde la web oficial no eh podido descargarlo.
Al que me pueda ayudar le agradezco.
Saludos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te está diciendo que está arrancando con un OpenJDK incluido en IntelliJ y ese sólo funciona para 64bit. Busca un JDK externo compilado para 32bit y cambia el idea.vmoptions para que apunte a ese JDK. Aunque es curioso que no funcione, porque, según la [documentación](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/JetBrains+Runtime+Environment), debería funcionar. Qué versión de IntelliJ estás intentando usar?

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alfabravo intentare hacerlo como tu dices espero tener exito saludos.

Comment: @Alfabravo La que estoy tratando de instalar es la Version: 2019.2.3